# Заполнение массива через функцию

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть следующий код

```
let levelName = "info" 
let message = "hello World"


let logsArray = []

    const  writeToFile = (levelName, message) => {

        const logsDir = './logs' 
        let data = `{"level": "${levelName.toUpperCase()}", "message": "${message}", "timestamp": "${getFormatedCurrenDate()}" } \r\n`

        logsArray.push(data)
}
```

Этот код, при вызове через npm start, пушит строку в массив logsArray, но только одну строку

```
[
  '{"level": "ERROR", "message": "Hello world", "timestamp": "2022-07-28T08:05:49" } \r\n'
]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении параметров, добавлялась вторая и третья строка в массив, как показано ниже?

```
[
  '{"level": "WARN", "message": "Hello world", "timestamp": "2022-07-28T09:24:27" } \r\n',
  '{"level": "WARN", "message": "Hello world", "timestamp": "2022-07-28T09:24:26" } \r\n',
  '{"level": "WARN", "message": "Hello world", "timestamp": "2022-07-28T08:05:59" } \r\n'
]
```

Comment: вызвать writeToFile?

Comment: writeToFile вызывается(иначе бы в массив ничего не добавлялось), но в другой части кода. Я этого не указывал, так как не относится к сути проблемы.

Comment: так может вы вызываете только один раз?  так ни вижу никаких проблем

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin  а можете глянуть код на гите? там расписано все подробнее и понятнее. 

Да, я вызываю функцию один раз, но никак не могу понять, как вызывать ее так, чтобы в массив записывалось логов больше, чем 1 или 2  (файл с кодом и массивом loggerFile.js)

https://github.com/BurningPenguin25/Logger.js
В файле readme расписаны цели

Comment: Ну так вызывайте её каждый раз, когда это необходимо. В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @PavelBodnar Я не понимаю, вы вызываете `loggerFile` только один раз в `index.js` и почему ожидаете что будет несколько вставок в массив? И о изменении каких параметров идёт речь? Где они меняются?

Comment: ну так вам же по идее этот логер надо вызывать при каждой ошибки или еще при каких событиях.

Answer (score 0):

Есть множество способов, вот один из них с помощью цикла for и дополнительного параметра.

```
let logsArray = []

const  writeToFile = (levelName, message,count=1) => {

        const logsDir = './logs' 
        for(let i=0;i<count;i++){
            logsArray.push(`{"level": "${levelName.toUpperCase()}", "message": "${message}", "timestamp": "${getFormatedCurrenDate()}" } \r\n`)
        }
}
```

Я бы ещё `logsArray` поместил бы внутрь функции `writeFile`.

Пример использования функции:

```
   writeToFile ('WARN','Hello world') ///Добавит 1 запись
   writeToFile ('WARN','Hello world',5) ///Добавит 5 записей
```

Comment: Там проблема не в `writeFile`, всё написано корректно у него, если посмотреть в репозиторий, автор просто вызывает ф-ию 1 раз. И тут не понятно, почему он вообще ожидает, что что-то будет 3 раза вызываться